# `Error lnk1181: cannot open input file 'Debug\Source.obj` when trying to create listing file

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, linker

I'm trying to get started with asm programming on Win 32 and, after searching the internet for instructions for a while and also using [Irvine's online tutorial](http://www.asmirvine.com/) on setting this up, successfully got the following program to compile and run using VS 2015 community edition:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall

option casemap:none

.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.CODE
main PROC
mov eax,5 ; move 5 to the eax register
add eax,6 ; add 6 to the eax register
INVOKE ExitProcess,0 
main ENDP
END main
```

(it's from Irvine's book).

Now I want to create a listing file. To this end I opened Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Microsoft Macro-Assembler and enabled 'Generate Preprocessed Source Listing' and 'List All Available Information' and added `$(ProjectName).lst` in the 'Assembled Code Listing File' entry. After that I get the error mentioned in the title when I try to build the project.

In fact, when I build the project (without these settings), no `.obj` file seems to be generated, just the `.exe` and `.pdb`. I can trigger building an `.obj` file by choosing the 'Enable Assembly Generated Code Listing' option (same path as above), but I still get the same error when I try to enable generation of the listing file as explained before. Any ideas?

(This is following instructions in Irvine's book, but without using his included files).

(I *did* disable my Anti Virus program before building).

Comment: Is your code (that you've shown) in a file named `Source.asm`?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, it is. (And the build result is Source.obj if I enable the option I mentioned in the last paragraph). The overall build result is 'test.exe'